# Sorting downloads folder with bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing script for my own needs to sort Downloads folder on my mac in bash.
I pass to the function parameters: source directory, destination directory and array of file extensions I want to move. My problem is that when function is in "find" line then it copies just one file with that extension but when I remove all variables and I put parameters directly then it works fine. What's going on ?

```
 function moveFaster(){
   clear
    src=$1
    dst=$2
    typ=$3
    if [ ! -d $dst ]
      then
        mkdir $dst
      fi

    for i in "${typ[@]}"
      do
        find $src -name "${i}" -exec mv {} ${dst} \;
      done


  }
```

Comment: Put 'set -x' towards the top, so it will echo everything it does.

Answer (score 5):

Each argument to a function is a scalar, and you're trying to pass an array. When you write

```
a=(foo bar qux)
moveFaster "$src" "$dst" "${a[@]}"
```

then moveFaster receives five arguments: `$src`, `$dst`, `foo`, `bar` and `qux`. If you write `moveFaster "$src" "$dst" "$a"` then only the first element of the array is passed to the function, because `$a` on its own expands to the first element of the array. Furthermore, your assignment to `typ` makes it a scalar variable.

Since you're passing a single array to the function, you can declare that it consists of all the remaining parameters.

```
moveFaster () {
  src="$1"
  dst="$2"
  shift 2
  typ=("$@")
  …
}
```

On a related note, your script will fail spectacularly if any of the file names involved contains whitespace or globbing characters (`?*\[`). To avoid this, respect this simple shell programming rule: **always put double quotes around variable substitutions** (unless you understand why they must not be present in a particular case).

```
function moveFaster(){
  src="$1"
  dst="$2"
  typ=("$@")
  if [ ! -d "$dst" ];  then mkdir -- "$dst"; fi
  for i in "${typ[@]}"; do
    find "$src" -name "${i}" -exec mv {} "${dst}" \;
  done
}
```

As an aside, you can do this reasonably easily with bash features alone, if you have bash version 4 or above. The `extglob` option allows extended glob patterns such as `@(PATTERN1|PATTERN2)`. The `globstar` option allows `**/PATTERN` to match files whose name matches `PATTERN` in subdirectories recursively.

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
mkdir -p /common/destination/directory
mv /path/to/source/**/@(*.txt|*.html|README) /common/destination/directory
```